# SBT 0.12.4 global configuration under Windows

Tags: windows, scala, configuration, sbt, config

Where should I put global sbt 0.12.4 configuration files (like *`plugins/build.sbt`* etc) under Windows?

I'm trying *`C:\Users\username\.sbt\plugins`*, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of sbt? 0.13 uses `~/.sbt/0.13/`.

Comment: @EugeneYokota i use 0.12.4

Comment: What's in your build.sbt ? did you define addSbtPlugin() ?

Answer (score 0):

Following this [link](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Global-Settings.html) I've created 'global.sbt' file under %USERPROFILE%\.sbt\0.13 and put my global settings there.